# Xcode 4.6.3 Storyboard Class and Subclass Reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I this this following stuff:

[image: UIScrollView]

And I have create a new `Objective-C category`

[image: MyScrollView implementation]

[image: MyScrollView implementation]

And after all on Identify inspector I have defined the Custom Class as `MyScrollView`

[image: Custom Class]

And when app start on iOS Simulator I received this message:

```
Unknown class MyScrollView in Interface Builder file.
```

This approach can be used to implement ViewController, but is not working to nested classes. Have any solution for this case?

Comment: I understand you are creating a category on UIScrollView, not a subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categories and subclasses are two different things. When you make a new file, you're choosing to add a category to UIScrollView; in your storyboard editor, you're trying to set the class of the view. The class is still UIScrollView; MyScrollView isn't a class. You (probably) want to make a subclass of UIScrollView instead.

Comment: I am really thankfull for your answer. I have a creppy'n paste project for knowledge purposes and all make much more sense!